# Dying light Outfits

Tags: dying-light

I've completed dying light and now I'm doing a 100% run and wanted to know what outfits there are and how to unlock them I have 
fresh clothes, athlete, runner, scout, survivor, and head hunter
Q: what outfits am I missing and how do I earn them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Fresh clothes - Fresh Clothes is a general outfit available for Kyle Crane in Dying Light. This is also the first outfit available in the game.
2. Athlete -  You can get this by buying the season pass.
3. Runner - It can be earned on level 6.
4. Scout - Scout is a general outfit available in Dying Light.
5. Survivor- Survivor is a general outfit available in Dying Light.
6. Headhunter - Headhunter is a general outfit available in Dying Light. It becomes available to the player from their player stash at Survival Rank 15.
7. Juggernaut - Juggernaut is a general outfit available in Dying Light.

There are also several DLC outfits.

Comment: While compiling a list from the wiki is moderately helpful. All of the "X is a general outfit available in Dying Light." are just stub articles, the outfits aren't actually available from the start. Do you have any more information about how these are unlocked?